# Fit GUID In 10 bytes?

Tags: sql, schema

I have a question.  I'm designing a SQL database that needs a table with a unique ID.  Due to constraints of the project, the unique ID has to fit in 10 bytes.  And has to be a globally unique number (can't ever be generated to the same value twice for this project, not necessarily for anything anywhere).

Have been debating between going with a GUID or just a large number that auto-increments.  Not sure the best solution here.

If a GUID can be made to fit within the 10 byte constraint, that would be the most options of uniqueness, I think.  But my question is, if that is even possible without losing the uniqueness I need?

If it's not possible, then I guess the only option is to go with an auto-incrementing number.

Thanks! (PS: This is my first Stack Overflow question!)

Comment: A guid is 16 bytes. You can't put 16 bytes in 10 bytes, in the same way that you can't put a gallon of milk in a bottle of 1 liter.

Comment: That is true... is there a way to compress it so it's represented in less than 16 bytes?

Comment: You can't guarantee that it is compressible. Some guid can be easily compressed. `00000000-0000-0000-00000000` can be surely compressed to less than 10 bytes, but `31415926-5358-9793-23846264` (it is the first 32 digits of PI) can't be compressed by any general purpose compressor to less than 16 bytes.

Comment: do you need the id to be random? why don't you use an autoincrement?

Comment: The id doesn't need to be random, just unique.  That's why I was also considering an autoincrement, if compressing it is not feasible.

Comment: you can't map 16 byte numbers to 10 byte numbers without repeating values. refer to first comment.

Comment: Ok, will just go with an autoincrement id number then for the table, since there's no way to compress it.  Thanks All!